# Is there any way to activate MTP connection on a phone with broken screen?

Tags: data-recovery, broken-screen

My phone's screen is broken and when I connect it to my laptop via USB it is in "Charge only" mode. I need to get my data out of the phone so I was wondering if there was any way to activate "MTP" or even USB debugging. Can starting the phone in the recovery mode help?

Answer (score 1):

If the broken screen still shows the display, I recommend connecting it to a a USB optical mouse with an OTG connector.

Try using `adb` if that is not case, but it works only when USB debugging is turned on.